# How can I handle tables with large data which I have to query upon joining in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 4 tables and following is their schema:

```
stocks =>
id: integer
quantity: integer
retailer_code: string
sku_code: string

sales =>
id: integer
retailer_name: string
retailer_code: string
salesman_id: integer

salesmen => 
id: integer
salesman_name: string
salesman_id: integer

tertiaries => 
id: integer
retailer_code: string
retailer_name: string
sku_code: string
name_of_model: string
secondary_sales_date: date
tertiary_sales_date: date
```

I am doing the following query to get data in the format below

```
SELECT 
f_t.retailer_code, f_t.retailer_name, f_t.sku_code, f_t.name_of_model, f_t.quantity, s_t.salesman_id, s_t.salesman_name, f_t.secondary_sale_date, f_t.tertiary_sale_date 
FROM 
  (SELECT 
   st.retailer_code, t.retailer_name, st.sku_code, t.name_of_model,  st.quantity, t.secondary_sale_date, t.tertiary_sale_date 
   FROM stocks st 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   tertiaries t 
   ON 
   t.retailer_code = st.retailer_code AND t.sku_code = st.sku_code  
   WHERE t.secondary_sale_date IS NOT NULL AND t.tertiary_sale_date IS NOT NULL
  ) f_t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   (SELECT sl.retailer_code, slm.salesman_id, slm.salesman_name 
   FROM sales sl 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   salesmen slm 
   ON sl.salesman_id=slm.salesman_id 
   WHERE slm.salesman_id IS NOT NULL
   ) s_t 
  ON 
  f_t.retailer_code=s_t.retailer_code;
```

retailer_code | retailer_name | sku_code | model_name | quantity | salesman_id | salesman_name | secondary_sales_date | tertiary_sales_date

These were the columns of the final result. Furthermore, I need to do queries on these rows which involves grouping and summation, etc.

The problem is each of these tables have around 10,000,000 i.e. in order of 10^7 or 10^8 number of records which makes it really slow for querying. But in the application I need to generate the report on command of user.
Note that these table gets updated when user wishes(data syncs from another api)

Comment: `LEFT JOIN t ... WHERE t.column IS NOT NULL`... Means a regular, INNER JOIN is performed.

Comment: In MySQL, unnecessary subqueries in the `FROM` clause tend to reduce performance, because they intermediate results are materialized, adding read/write overhead and preventing the use of indexes.